# Indented tree in nvd3.js : searching for a specific node and opening all parents

Tags: jquery, d3.js, data-visualization, nvd3.js

I am currently learning data visualization with jquery and nvd3.js.
I have set a page like the example ( http://nvd3.com/ghpages/indentedtree.html ) with an input text field working fine with just alert(); function.

What i want to do is :

- Find all nodes which span text value is equal to user query
- Open all their parents nodes

So, what is the best way to access nodes ? Have I to use Jquery selectors or is there a better way ?

**EDIT :**

My json is like :

```
status: true, 
_values: [
{
    status: false, 
    _values: [
        {
            status: false, 
            _values: [], 
            attr: "text", 
            key: "2"
        }, 
        ...
    ]
    attr: "text",
    key: "1"
}
```

Finally i have found another way to catch all parents nodes from top to leaf of a key.
Now all i need is the correct syntax in nvd3.js (if different of d3.js) to do this :

```
for(parent in parents) {
    open parent
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_select?

Answer (score 0):

this will be helpful:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections

> D3 uses CSS3 to select elements.

i would try something like this:

```
d3.selectAll("value"=d3.select('#input-id').value)
  .parent()
  .[required action]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In fact i don't understand how to apply this selections functionalities in the example i linked. Can you explain me a bit more about it ?